# How to do page caching in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-cli

i am working on angular application. And wants to implement caching for user list- problem is when open any user detail and coming back to user list everytime reload.

I searched and found i can do http caching.

Is there any way to maintain home page state?

Comment: service workers are your best bet for this usecase.

Comment: Ok thanks for quick suggestions, let me try